# What is the Complexity of something with 2 algorithms that can solve it

Tags: algorithm

There are 2 algorithms that can give the correct output for a given problem.

Given that the complexity of one algorithm is **theta(n log(n))** while the other is **theta(n)**, what is the complexity of the **problem?** e.g. is it Big O of n log(n), Big Omega of n log(n) or the other way?

Since algorithm is about worst case scenarios do we also consider the worst case scenario in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Since

> f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))

means that f is bounded both above and below by g asymptotically, and

> f(n) ∈ O(g(n))

means that f is bounded above by g asymptotically, clearly

> f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)) ⇒ f(n) ∈ O(g(n)).

Since the problem can be solved by an Θ(n) algorithm, the fact that it can be also solved by an Θ(n log(n)) algorithm is just noise intended to distract: the problem is no harder than Θ(n) (and may, in fact, be simpler). The problem complexity is certainly not bounded below by n log(n), so it isn't Ω() of <strike>anything</strike> n log(n) and there's no evidence given that it is Ω(n) either (although it is trivially Ω(1)).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. If f(n) ∈ Θ(n) doesn't it mean that it is bounded both above and below by n and is thus also ∈ Ω(n)?

Comment: While it's true that you can usually prove that any algorithm has a lower bound of Ω(n) to solve a problem (after all, every element must usually be read at least once), proving that a *particular* algorithm has such a lower bound says nothing about the class of al *possible* algorithms. After all, showing the existence of an Ω(n lg n) did not preclude the existence of an Ω(n) algorithm.

Comment: @daidaidai - When you're talking about a fixed f(n), you are right. But I'm making a distinction (as you did in the question) between the complexity of the algorithm(s) and the complexity of the problem. The problem complexity is the complexity of the least complex algorithm that solves the problem. No information is provided that the Θ(n) algorithm is the best one can do with the problem.